# Apache2 Virtual Host Restrict to Localhost

Tags: security, apache-2.2, virtualhost

So here's the deal.

I have multiple virtual host. Each virtual is a separate domain. Each domain is for separate applications. Lets say I have virtual hosts for:

http://*.abc.com
http://*.def.com
http://foo.com

I then a separate application, which is a RESTful HTTP api for the foo.com application.

What i want to achieve is essentially back channel communication between *.abc.com and *.def.com to api.foo.com. So that *.abc.com, *.def.com and foo.com are publicly accessible (this i have already set setup). But access api.foo.com is only accessible when being requested from the same server.

**My criteria is:**

- a 404 should be served to anyone attempting to browse to api.foo.com (not permission denied)
- access to api.foo.com is restricted to an IP or IP range

I have achieve this by:

- not setting a dns record for api.foo.com so anyone trying to access it will receive a 404.
- creating an ip based virtual host for 127.0.0.1:80 and added the follow rule to /etc/hosts

  127.0.0.1   api.foo.com

This works exactly as desired. But is this the correct way to achieve a private virtual host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good solution for me. You could even scale this to multiple servers if your site grows.

One small hint: Clients wouldn't receive an 404 error, their browser will report them it couldn't find the host to begin with. A 404 means that the browser talked to the server, but the server couldn't finde the requested document.

Comment: Either way is fine. I simply want the api.foo.com sub domain to appear completely non-existent.

Comment: If api.foo.com only exists in the local hosts file, then you'll get that invisibility, certainly.  I would also recommend using mod_access to add IP-based restrictions to access the site, since you can be sure in this case that all legitimate connections would be coming from the local machine.

Comment: is that equivalent to setting "Order Deny,Allow", "Deny from all", "Allow <ip1, ip2, ipn>" ? because that is what I have in place atm